# Update the Activity based on what item is selected in the Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, androidplot

In the current Activity I'm printing a graph (using Androidplot) of the closing prices of a selected stock from the previous activity.
In this activity I have a spinner of a list of indicators the user can overlay.
Now I want the graph to be redrawn with this new selection from the spinner.
I did try refreshing/reloading the page onItemSelected but that causes the page to keep refreshing even without waiting for a user input.

```
public class DispGraph extends Activity {

private XYPlot plotstock;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph);

    // PRINTING SELECTED STOCK_NAME

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String sname = bundle.getString("SN");
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText(sname);

    // INDICATOR LIST

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Indicators, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    String iname = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});

    //PASSING STOCK-TICKER & INDICATOR TO PHP



    // PLOTTING GRAPH

    plotstock = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);
    Number[] series1Numbers = ind;
    Number[] series2Numbers = closing;

    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, iname);
    XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers),SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Closing Price");

    plotstock.setDomainLabel("Date");
    plotstock.setRangeLabel("Price");

    plotstock.addSeries(series1,new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 200, 0), Color.rgb(0,100, 0), null, new PointLabelFormatter(Color.TRANSPARENT)));
    plotstock.addSeries(series2,new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 200), Color.rgb(0, 0, 100),null, new PointLabelFormatter(Color.TRANSPARENT)));

    plotstock.setTicksPerRangeLabel(2);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your current approach, each time the user select a spinner value your current activity will be started again, so it will be put on Android Stack. Soon, if the user change your spinner n times, you should press n + 1 times to close your app. This is a really annoying behavior.

Well, I do not know the AndroidPlot, but looking its API I found the method redraw.So, i think you could try on that way:

Every time the user select a spinner value, i can do your modifications on `plotstock` after call `plotstock.redraw()`

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Change the graphics value here!
        plotstock.redraw();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }});
```

Comment: I did already try that. It still displays the first selected 'iname'(Indicator) & the same graph.

Comment: You are not changing your iname variable. Try that inside onItemSelected method. `iname = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString()`

Comment: hey thanks man but that didn't really work, i just made a pop up List View instead.